# Is it possible to duplicate the view of the same source file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm doing some manteinance to a .cpp file with eclipse and I need to compare two methods. It's very uncomfortable to jump ahead and back to check differences.

Is there a way to duplicate the view of the same source file, in order to compare them side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file and use `Window > New Editor` to open a second editor on the file. Then drag the title tab of the second editor and Eclipse will show on outline of how it is going to arrange the two editors. You can arrange the two editors vertically or horizontally.

Update:
Eclipse 4.4 Luna (currently only available as Milestone builds) adds support for splitting the editor directly using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>.